# How to change the foreground of a specific word in a textblock?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got a textblock in which the user sees a stacktrace, like this:

> System.ArgOutOfRangeExc.: 
>   Argument is out of range.
>   Parametername: index
>   at System.Collections.ArrayList.getItem(Int32 index)
>       //...
>       at SomethingElse.formData.formData_CloseForm(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)

The idea is, that everything like "System...." gets colored grey and the rest of the stacktrace (here: "at SomethingElse....") should not be colored.

I dont know how and where to start and how to manage this problem. Any solutions? I'm working with C# and WPF

EDIT: The text in the textbox is not static. The text changes everytime the user clicks on a row in a DataGrid, so I need to do that programmatically (working with Substring will get very complicated)

Comment: You could always use a control like this one: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor

Comment: Have you looked at the [RichTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: What's wrong with using several text blocks in one panel?

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft I'll try to learn the ropes of RichTextBoxes

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova I dont think that would be elegant coding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use a number of [`Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run(v=vs.110).aspx) elements inside your `TextBlock`. Each `Run` can have it's own formatting. Take this simple example:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="14" Margin="20">
    <Run Text="This is Green," Foreground="Green" />
    <Run Text="this is Red" Foreground="Red" />
    <Run Text="and this is Blue AND Bold" Foreground="Blue" FontWeight="Bold" />
</TextBlock>
```

[image]

Please note that the `Run.Text` property is a `DependencyProperty`, so you can also data bind its value. This can also be accomplished programmatically:

```
<TextBlock Name="TextBlock" FontSize="14" Margin="20" />
```

...

```
private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Run run = new Run("This is Green,");
    run.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
    TextBlock.Inlines.Add(run);
    run = new Run(" this is Red");
    run.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
    TextBlock.Inlines.Add(run);
    run = new Run(" and this is Blue AND Bold");
    run.Foreground = Brushes.Blue;
    run.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
    TextBlock.Inlines.Add(run);
}
```

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that the `Text` property of the `Run` element only became a dependency property in .NET 4.

Comment: The text is not static. Maybe I should mention, that the text changes everytime the user clicks on a row in a DataGrid. (Otherwise **I** have to color the text for every exception)

Comment: That's exactly why I added the programmatic example for you. No solution will automatically colour specific words for you without you programming them to do so.

Comment: So I have to do something with substring?

Comment: You'll need to split (`string.Split`) the messages on any words that you want to colour, add each block into a new `Run`, add your required formatting for the highlighted words and then add them all into the `Inlines` property of the `TextBlock` that is to be displayed.